# An empty code block gets added after an embedded list containing code

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, code-formatting

If I have a code block which is created using three backticks (```` ``` ````) inside a nested list, a second empty code block sometimes gets added after the list. For example, this markdown code:

````
1. Testing a strange bug:
    - ```
      testing something
      ```
````

Renders like this:

> 1. Testing a strange bug:
>
>    - ```
>      testing something
>      ```

Here is a screenshot so that you can understand what this question is about even after this bug gets fixed:

> [image]

This bug seems to only appear if there is a certain number of spaces before the second list. For example, this renders normally:

````
1. Testing a strange bug:
      - ```
        testing something
        ```
````

The only difference between this code and the previous one is that the second list containing the code is indented two extra spaces.

Also, this bug doesn't appear in the preview when editing posts, it only appears after having submitted the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested to confirm that this bug was fixed a while ago and that indeed appears to be the case. I've updated to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: The bug is here again.